# R: Fill column of a data frame with values of differently sized data frame

Tags: r, conditional-statements

Consider the following data frames:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C"),
            y = c("abl", "rtg", "jaf", "rlt", "thk", "lpv"))

z = c(rep("abl", 4), rep("rtg", 2), rep("jaf",1), rep("zfw", 3), "thk")
dat <- data.frame(z = z, group = rep(NA, length(z)))
```

I want `dat$group` to be filled with the value of `df$x` from that row, where the value of `df$y` matches `dat$z`. The final data frame should look like that:

```
 z group
abl     A
abl     A
abl     A
abl     A
rtg     A
rtg     A
jaf     A
zfw    NA
zfw    NA
zfw    NA
thk     C
```

I just can't figure out how to do this.

The code that I tried so far:

```
dat$group[which(dat$z == df$y)] <- df$x[which(df$y == dat$z)]
dat$group[which(dat$z %in% df$y)] <- df$x[which(df$y %in% dat$z)]
```

It is throwing an error and not producing the desired result. 
How can I get the final data frame?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple, R base solution is by using `match`:

```
dat$group <- df$x[match(dat$z,df$y)]
dat
     z group
1  abl     A
2  abl     A
3  abl     A
4  abl     A
5  rtg     A
6  rtg     A
7  jaf     A
8  zfw  <NA>
9  zfw  <NA>
10 zfw  <NA>
11 thk     C
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is a `join` operation:

```
dplyr::left_join(dat, df, by = c('z' = 'y'))

     z group    x
1  abl    NA    A
2  abl    NA    A
3  abl    NA    A
4  abl    NA    A
5  rtg    NA    A
6  rtg    NA    A
7  jaf    NA    A
8  zfw    NA <NA>
9  zfw    NA <NA>
10 zfw    NA <NA>
11 thk    NA    C
```

The [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right?noredirect=1&lq=1) will have several different strategies, but I think it would be helpful to know the appropriate term for this kind of operation.